# cypress somehow override config "pageLoadTimeout" to 1000ms through in cypress.json I set "pageLoadTimeout" to 3000m

Tags: node.js, typescript, cypress

Current behavior
Note: I have override *pageLoadTimeout* via command but it still doesn't work.
npx cypress open --config pageLoadTimeout=30000

[click here error image: pageloadtime been override to 1000ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6JM.jpg)

cypress_timeout

Desired behavior
Same as cypress.json

Test code to reproduce

```
{
"ignoreTestFiles": ".ts",
"defaultCommandTimeout": 5000,
"pageLoadTimeout": 50000,
"baseUrl":"http://www.google.com",
"env": {
"pageLoadTimeout": 80000,
"defaultCommandTimeout": 30000
},
"testFiles": "**/.{feature,features}",
"screenshotsFolder": "cypress/results/screenshots",
"pluginsFile":"cypress/plugins/index.js",
"videosFolder": "cypress/results/videos",
"reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
"reporterOptions": {
"mochaFile": "cypress/results/reports/junit/test-results.[hash].xml",
"testsuitesTitle": false
},
"retries": {
"runMode": 1,
"openMode": 1
}
}
```

Versions
Cypress version: 7.4.0
Browser: Chrome91 and Electron 89
Operating System: Mac

Answer (score 0):

You have to write these outside of env:

```
"pageLoadTimeout": 80000,
"defaultCommandTimeout": 30000
```

So your `cypress.json` should be:

```
{
  "ignoreTestFiles": ".ts",
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 5000,
  "pageLoadTimeout": 50000,
  "baseUrl": "http://www.google.com",
  "pageLoadTimeout": 80000,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
  "testFiles": "**/.{feature,features}",
  "screenshotsFolder": "cypress/results/screenshots",
  "pluginsFile": "cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "videosFolder": "cypress/results/videos",
  "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "cypress/results/reports/junit/test-results.[hash].xml",
    "testsuitesTitle": false
  },
  "retries": {
    "runMode": 1,
    "openMode": 1
  }
}
```